# Using VBA WordEditor to align multiple tables horizontally in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, formatting, copy-paste

I'm trying to use VBA WordEditor to compile an Outlook e-mail which copies some tables from a workbook and pastes them into the e-mail. I'm trying to make the table objects lie on the same horizontal line to one another. My code is able to place them side by side, but one table is slightly lower then the other and I have tried but failed to move it upwards.

The code below what I'm currently using to test run the pasting process - note it is intended to be looped so that I can paste multiple tables, right now however I'm just trying out with 2.

Here's an example of what it outputs

[image]

Here's an example of what I want to achieve. Here I can only do this by manually dragging the table.

[image]

```vb
Dim tblScore2, tblScore1 As Word.Table
Dim rngTarget, rngHolder As Word.Range
Dim ws_sum As Worksheet
dim wdDoc as Word.Document

''''''
'some other code here
''''''
With ws_sum
    .Range(.Cells(9, 3), .Cells(12, 7)).Copy 
End With


Set rngTarget = wdDoc.Range(0, 0)
Set rngHolder = rngTarget.Duplicate

rngTarget.InsertBefore vbCr
rngTarget.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1

rngTarget.Paste

rngHolder.InsertBefore vbCr
Set rngTarget = rngHolder.Duplicate
rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

rngTarget.Paste


Set tblScore1 = wdDoc.Tables(1)
Set tblScore2 = wdDoc.Tables(2)

tblScore1.Rows.WrapAroundText = True
tblScore2.Rows.WrapAroundText = True

'was trying to make this work but it hasn't yielded any results..
tblScore2.Range.Move wdParagraph, -2
```

I've tried changing the table properties, i.e. `Rows.Alignment`, `.HorizontalPosition` but none of them seem to even elicit a response, aside from `.Alignment` which only shifts the table left and right in the specified direction but still does not change the height difference - what is interesting is perhaps when editing the horizontal position of the tables in word, it does indeed produce the response I wanted, but its only when I am working in Outlook that it doesn't work. I've come to suspect it has something to do with the tables lying on different paragraphs, but trying `.Move` and `.MoveUp` has not worked out either. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you would turn on the display of non-printing characters in Word so that we could see things like paragraph marks. That would tell us more about what is affecting the formatting. **However** I do *not* recommend making the tables "floating" (freely positioned on the page). This is not going to be stable. Better would be a nested table for each in two adjacent table cells.

Comment: Can you share the workbook?

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes now that you mentioned it using adjacent nested tables would be far simpler and manageable compared to what I wanted to do. I guess my question isn't quite as relevant anymore. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @0m3r As CindyMeister has pointed out a better way to approach this issue, my question is no longer relevant, sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure whether it would be best you delete the question, or whether I should compose my suggestion as an Answer, if others might have the same question. For me it's so obvious that I can't judge. What do you think?